# How can I turn a generated php website automatically to HTML once an hour?

Tags: php, html

I have a website that loads very slowly because it integrates several data directly from streams from kimonolabs.com (via csv). I am not that familiar with databases, so it gets the data via pure php requests.

I know the best way would be a cronjob of the csv's importing to a db and then request the local db, but I don't want to get that complicated - for my purposes and for google SEO I would like a solution where the generated index.php will automatically will be copied to the index.html every hour - because thats how often the stream gets updated. Manually thats no problem (just open source code in browser copy & paste).

Source code for an example PHP Request:

```
<?php $file_handle = fopen("kimonolabs.com/api/csv/xxx";, "r"); 
while (!feof($file_handle) ) 
{ $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024); 

if ($line_of_text[0] == 'EXAMPLE'){ 

print "<p>" . $line_of_text[0] . "&nbsp;" . $line_of_text[2] . "</p>";}; 

} 

fclose($file_handle); ?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What did you try so far? Are cron jobs supported by your server?

Comment: Also, if loading is your issue and you have multiple streams, have you considered loading that data via AJAX?

Comment: Have you considered caching the results of these requests for stream data? It doesn't take much more than three or four lines of code wrapped around each stream request

Comment: They, first of fall - thanks! Unfortunately I am not really familiar with cronjobs and AJAX to integrate it - do you have some resources for me where I could go deeper into the topic?

Comment: @MarkBaker no, but that sounds terrific! This is the code:

<?php

$file_handle = fopen("https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/csv/xxx", "r");

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

$line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
if ($line_of_text[0] == 'EXAMPLE'){
print "<p>" . $line_of_text[0] . "&nbsp;" . $line_of_text[2] . "</p>";};

}

fclose($file_handle);

?>

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the simplest option would be to rename your existing `index.php` to `real_index.php` and make `index.php` to be like this:

```
$cache = 'cache.html';

if(!is_readable($cache) || filemtime($cache) < time() - 3600) {

    ob_start();
    include 'real_index.php';
    file_put_contents($cache, ob_get_clean());
}

readfile($cache);
```

Comment: Thanks! that sounds perfect. 2 Questions:

1) It is still very slow for the first one to click on it, right? How can I fix that? 
2) That kills all SEO efforts I guess?

Comment: @creal: 1) yes, the first call will be slow. Even worse, a race condition is also possible. If this is not desired, consider the cron job. 2) no, for google your site looks just as before.

Comment: thanks! I just renamed the cache.html to index.html and the index.php to index-cache.php. I set up a cronjob that opens the index-cache.php every 15minutes which reads out the index-real.php! Works perfectly and is always fast! :)

Comment: @creal: glad to hear it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Setting a cronjob up is the most straightforward way to achieve that, because you're basically trying to schedule the data output from the .php file to an index.html file.

Another variation would be to output your index as a .php file and not an .html one, using something like memcache, Redis or even phpFastCache with an expiration time of one hour for the csv data.

Other than that, I see no direct solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea. put it in a file and place the file along with index.php and setup a cron to execute this file every hour. Rhis by no mean is the best way to go. You must consider Ajax Loading or Caching..

```
<?php
// Create a stream
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$file = file_get_contents('http://www.yoururl.com/index.php', false, $context);

file_put_contents('index.html', $file);
?>
```